# How do I hide or disable the Responsive Web Tester on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design

I can't find out how to get rid of this Chrome responsive web tester.   It shows up without warning and it's really annoying.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the Chrome developer tools.

To disable it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> or push the following button on your developer tools window/pane:

[image: "Toggle device mode" button]

Comment: Oh, so they changed it.  Thanks!

Comment: @TheHawk Happy to help. Remember to accept the answer if you feel it answered your question. :)